# A condition on where an intermediate field is the fixed field of a subgroup of the Galois group.

Tags: abstract-algebra

This is a question from Fenrick's [*Introduction to the Galois Correspondence*](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1461272858).

Specifically, it is a question from problem 1.4 in chapter 3 on page 146.
Let $K$, $L$, and $F$ be fields with $K\subset L\subset F$. Let $G=Gal_K F$ and let $H<G$. Show that if $\tau (u)=u $ for all $u\in L$ and $[L:K]\geq (G:H)$, then $L=H'$, where $H'$ is the fixed field of $H$.

My question is this: what is $\tau $? Fenrick does not specify. I have some guesses, such as that $\tau $ must be an arbitrary element of $H$, but I'd rather not try to answer the problem while having guessed the wrong hypothesis about $\tau $.
Note that I am not looking for a solution to the problem in the text, merely a clarification on notation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're correct -- The problem should read

> ... Show that if $\tau(u) = u$ for all $u \in L$ and $\tau \in H$ and moreover $[L:K] \geq (G:H)$, then $L = H'$ is the fixed field of $H$.

---

I hope this helps ^_^

Comment: Thank you very much.

Comment: @MikeWills. Happy to help! If this answered your question you should mark it as such by hitting the green checkmark so that other users know how to spend their time ^_^.